# tuleap can't find tracker admin link

Tags: tuleap

I'am evaluating Tuleap version 7.2.99.63. and I can't find the tracker admin tools. I want to add a new role to the story form and there is no tracker admin link in my version.

Any idea?

Philippe Delrieu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that sounds like either you don't have the permissions, either you're looking in the wrong place. The administration is per tracker; the link should be towards the top of the page. You'll then be looking to "manage field usage". If you think your version is the problem then maybe upgrade https://tuleap.net/doc/en/installation-guide/update.html?highlight=upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your help. You're right I wasn't at the right place. I thought it was in the project admin tools.